# Was the first Leto II born with prescience?

Tags: books, dune

The first Leto II dies towards the end of book 1 in the Dune series of book and very little is said about him but is it me tines anywhere if he has 'prescience'? He was half Fremen and the son of Muad'dib, although Chani wasn't in the high spice diet she was for the twins in book 2, but was he too young to show any signs?